# findOneAndUpdate does not update me - Nodejs, Express, Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am doing an update of a mongodb document in nodejs, I am using mongoose, and I am trying to do it with the code but it returns null. I would like to know if there is something wrong in my code, or if it can be updated using the "$and" y in the search for the document to update.

```
await stockDB.findOneAndUpdate({$and : [{Codigo: Codigo}, {Sucursal: SucursalDe}]},{
    CantidadTotal:CantidadTotal,
    $push : {HistorialMovimiento: HistorialMovimiento}
  })
```

Comment: Please translate this question into English (the official language of this site) or ask on one of those sites:
[Stackoverflow en Español](https://es.stackoverflow.com), 
[Stackoverflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com), 
[Stackoverflow на русском](https://ru.stackoverflow.com), and 
[Stackoverflow 日本語で](https://jp.stackoverflow.com).
Here on the main-site, non-English questions will be closed as "*needs details or clarity*" or "*because it is not in English*" and eventually deleted. 
[Read this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/2275490).

Comment: Thanks for translating the question. Please translate the non-English part of the title as well.

Comment: Thanks Vickel and Cigien, and I'm sorry

Comment: What do you mean "image code"?

Comment: I mean the code bellow

Comment: The `$and` is not needed in that query, but it is not harmful.  The null return suggests that no document matched.  If you run findOne instead of findOneAndUpdate, does it return any documents?

Comment: Yes, when I run the findOne return the correct document but when I try update with the findOneAndUpdate returns a null and I don't know why